# Execution format error which executing docker on AWS hosted Jumpbox

Tags: docker, redis

```
sudo docker run --platform linux/amd64 --entrypoint=sh -it cd.artifactory.ext.national.com.au/redis:7.0.11-rhel
```

Executing this command is giving error:

> exec /usr/bin/sh: exec format error

I am trying to execute this command on Jumpbox hosted on AWS, and after executing this >sh portal gets populated to connect with Redis Cluster.

Purpose: Need to connect to redis using Docker on AWS hosted Jumpbox.

```
UserID@HOST ~ % docker run --entrypoint=sh -it cd.artifactory.ext.national.com.au/redis:7.0.11-rhel
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
sh-4.4#
```

Expecting this which works on my local machine.

Answer (score -1):

The error message "exec format error" indicates a mismatch between the architecture of the Docker image and the architecture of the host machine.

In your case, the image is built for the AMD64 (x86_64) architecture, but the host machine on AWS is an ARM64 architecture. That's why you are getting this error.

To resolve this issue, you should use an image that is compatible with the architecture of your AWS instance. In your case, you need an image compatible with the ARM64 architecture.

You can try pulling an ARM64-compatible Redis image. For example:

```
docker run --entrypoint=sh -it arm64v8/redis:7.0.11-alpine
```

Make sure to replace arm64v8/redis:7.0.11-alpine with the appropriate image for your use case. You can find ARM64-compatible images on Docker Hub or other container registries.
Additionally, if you're running this on an AWS EC2 instance, make sure your EC2 instance type is compatible with the image architecture you want to run. For ARM64, you might want to use instance types like a1, m6g, or others that are based on ARM architecture.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: AI generated answers are banned from SO